# How to specify path(like npm --prefix) in npx?

Tags: npm, npx

This is my folder structure:

```
project/
└── test_cases
    └── package.json
```

The working dir is `project/`. I want to run eslint (an npm package) from working dir. I dont wish to cd into test_case. I install the same package from work dir by
`sudo npm install --prefix  test_cases/`.

Theres no such option for npx. `npx eslint` from working dir downloads from the internet.
I want to run them from the test_cases dir. Help!

Comment: Could you find a solution for this?

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npx/issues/74

Answer (score 5):

I managed to work around this problem by using

```
npm exec --prefix test_cases eslint
```

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned in github issue in npm@7 and above you can specify `--workspace` option for this:

```
npx -w test_cases eslint
```

https://github.com/npm/npx/issues/74#issuecomment-676092733